# RxSwift Observable.empty() is calling onNext

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

detect when reached tableview bottom
if not bottom `return Observable.empty()`
if tableview is bottom `return Observable.just(())`

as i Know is `Observable.empty()` is not calling onNext

but `empty()` or `just()` calling onNext

```
tableView.rx.contentOffset
            .map {
                self.isNearTheBottomEdge(contentOffset: $0, self.tableView) && self.postModel.isLoadingComplete.value
                    ? Observable.just(())
                    : Observable.empty()
            }
            .throttle(3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)

            .subscribe(onNext: {
                print("reached bottom")
                self.postModel.nextPage.onNext(())
            },onCompleted: {
                print("complete")
            }
            )
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

`return Observable.empty()` in debug but  always `print("reached bottom")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have `subscribe(onNext)` to be not called on Observable.empty(), just change `.map{}` to `.flatMap{}`

```
tableView.rx.contentOffset
            .flatMap {
                self.isNearTheBottomEdge(contentOffset: $0, self.tableView) && self.postModel.isLoadingComplete.value
                    ? Observable.just(())
                    : Observable.empty()
            }
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627902/rxswift-map-and-flatmap-difference) you can read about difference between `map` vs `flatMap`