# How to observe upper Observables with flatMap in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, flatmap

Differences between `map` and `flatMap` of `RxSwift` has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49779175/1084174). Now I want to observe the upper observable instance when the changes happen to it's inner observable. **How can I do so?**

Let's see the example,

```
func testFlatMap() {

    let bag = DisposeBag()

    struct Player {
        var age: Int
        var score: BehaviorSubject<Int>
    }

    let male = Player(age: 28, score: BehaviorSubject(value: 80))

    let player = PublishSubject<Player>()

    player.asObservable()
        .flatMap { $0.score.asObservable() }
        .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
        .disposed(by: bag)

    player.on(.next(male))
    male.score.on(.next(100))
}
```

In this above example the output is,

```
80
100
```

as expected. But I want to know the the full Player object status (i.e. `age` of the player) inside subscribe block `.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })` but it's only getting the `score`. **How can I do so?**

My expected output is,

```
Player (where I can access both age:28 and score:80)
Player (where I can access both age:28 and score:100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be:

```
player.asObservable()
    .flatMap { Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just($0.age), $0.score.asObservable()) }
```

From a category theory POV, this is considered a cleaner approach (you are "lifting" the age value into the monad,) but YMMV.

Also, Subjects should never be held in `var`, they should always be `let`s. It makes no sense to replace a Subject with a different one.

It would likely be better in the long run to remove the subject from your Player struct and just make it:

```
struct Player {
    var age: Int
    var score: Int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You returning an observable of scores from `flatMap` so only a score is available downstream. Instead, you want to return an observable of player info. You can attach age to a score by using additional `map` operator and closing over player argument:

```
player.asObservable()
      .flatMap { p in
          p.score.asObservable()
                 .map { score in (age: p.age, score: p.score) } }
      .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
      .disposed(by: bag)
```

Comment: Your suggestion works but is there any alternative cleaner way to avoid `map`?

Comment: I don't know of any. Maybe there is some rx operator which does basically the same, or you can wrap it into a custom rx operator. It's pretty much standard approach. Languages like scala or c# use comprehension syntax to make it cleaner, but it works the same under the hood.